# Copy from a text file and write to another file the lines numbered

Tags: python

My question is simple.

My task is to read a text file named cities.txt with countries and capitals 
(e.g. the first three lines are:

Aberdeen, Scotland

Adelaide, Australia

Algiers, Algeria

)

and write to another text file named out.txt these contents numbered
(e.g.

1: Aberdeen, Scotland

2: Adelaide, Australia

3: Algiers, Algeria

)

My code so far is:

```html
try:
    with open('cities.txt', 'r') as f:
        with open('out.txt', 'w') as m:
            lines = f.read()
            #missing code
except:
    print('Error')
else:
    with open('out.txt', 'r') as m:
        content = m.read()
    print(content)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it, like so:

```
with open('cities.txt') as infile, open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    in_lines = infile.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(in_lines, start=1):
        outfile.write('{}: {}'.format(i, line))
```

The text written to the `out.txt`:

```
1: Aberdeen, Scotland
2: Adelaide, Australia
3: Algiers, Algeria
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop over each line in the input file and write to the output - and use a counter to keep track of the line number:

```
with open('cities.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as m:
        l = 1
        for line in f:
            m.write("{}: {}".format(l, line))
            l += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it short by opening the files on one line

```
with open(r'bla.txt', 'r') as fd, open(r'bla2.txt', 'w') as fd2:
    count = 1
    for line in fd.readlines():
        fd2.write(str(count) + ': ' + line)
        count += 1
```